# multiple image list failed to be displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to display my multiple image list which I uploaded my specific product. but when I using a loop for display, I don't understand why?.here is my code:

Model

```
//model for multiple images

  public class Photo1
    {
        [Key]
        public int PhotoId { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
    }



//main model

 public class Shop
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "product name")]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Price { get; set; }


        public String Image { get; set; }
        public String Image1 { get; set; }

        public List<Photo1> Photos { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Category")]

        public int? CategoryTypeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CategoryTypeId")]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "SubCategory")]

        public int? SubCategoryTypeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SubCategoryTypeId")]
        public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Controller

```
        [HttpGet]

        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
          

            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var product = _db.Shop.Include(c => c.Category).Include(c => c.SubCategory).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
          

            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(product);
        }

    }
```

Details.cshtml

```
@model DigitalShop.Models.Shop






@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}


<br />
<h2 class="text-danger"> Product Details</h2>
                </br></br>

@*<div class="col-8 position-relative ">
        <img src="~/@Model.Image" width="425px" height="200px" sizes="cover" style="background-size:cover" />

    </div>*@
<form method="post" asp-action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1 ml-4">

            <img src="~/@Model.Image" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
            </br></br>
            @*<img src="~/@Model.Image1" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">*@
            </br></br>
           @if (Model.Photos != null)
            {
                @foreach (var photo in Model.Photos)
                {
                    @if (photo != null)
                    {
                        <img src="~/@photo.Image" alt="Card Image" class="card-img-top" style="height: 120px;" onclick="myFunction(this);"/>
                    }
                }
            }
            

        </div>

        <div class="col-4 container">
            <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
            <img src="~/@Model.Image" class="active" id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
            <div id="imgtext"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <h2><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> @Model.Name</h2>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            </br>

            <h4>@Model.Price $</h4></br>
            <small class="text-danger">Clearence</small>

            <hr>


            </br></br></br></br>





            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 spinner-block">
                <div class="number-spinner">

                    <div class="input-group number-spinner">
                        <b class="mr-4"> <label asp-for="@Model.Quantity"></label></b></br>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number btncartsniper" data-type="minus" data-dir="dwn"><span class="fa fa-minus fa-sm"></span></button>
                        </span>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.Quantity" class="form-control input-number Snippper_qty" value="0" type="number">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number btncartsniper" data-type="plus" data-dir="up"><span class="fa fa-plus fa-sm"></span></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>




            </div>
            </br>
            @*@if (leathers != null)
                {*@
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger form-control" asp-action="Remove" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Remove To Cart</button>
            @*}*@
            @*else
                {*@
            <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" class="btn btn-dark form-control" />
            @*}*@

        </div>


    </div>



    <div>

        <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-danger">Back To List</a>
    </div>
</form>




@section Scripts{

    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");

    }



    <script>
        function myFunction(imgs) {
            var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
            var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
            expandImg.src = imgs.src;
            imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
            expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
}
```

my output is :

[image]

but I want to show my all multiple photos of every product. I failed to understand what's the solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop through Photos.
That's what the error indicates. It tries to find the enumerator of Shop (Model), while you're intending to loop through photos.

```
        @if (Model.Photos != null)
        {
            @foreach (var photo in Model.Photos)
            {
                @if (photo.Image != null)
                {
                    <img src="~/@photo.Image" alt="Card Image" class="card-img-top" style="height: 120px;"/>
                }
            }
        }
```

You should also include Photos to the product you're returning, otherwise the list will be null.

Comment: not working. for that, I found a new error    ``` Photo1 does not contain the definition of photos and not accessible extension method" Photos.accepting a first argument type could be found```

Comment: I updated my answer. You also have to change the code inside the loop because you are already in the list.

Comment: I copied your code on my project. but again found a new error ``` An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. ```

Comment: :) please send a screenshot of the error you see. Also, did you copy the updated answer?

Comment: but I not found the system to send the screenshot to the comment section.

Comment: All Error ```
C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\DigitalShop\DigitalShop\DigitalShop\Areas\Customer\Views\ShopShow\Details.cshtml

Expected a "{" but found a "@". Block statements must be enclosed in "{" and "}". You cannot use single-statement control-flow statements in CSHTML pages. For example, the following is not allowed: @if(isLoggedIn) <p>Hello, @user</p> Instead, wrap the contents of the block in "{}": @if(isLoggedIn) { <p>Hello, @user</p> }
+
                @foreach (var photo in Model.Photos)
 ```

Comment: This error should be fixed with the updated answer. It just implies the rules of nested blocks. Please try again and let me know :)

Comment: I copied your code newly. found no error.but can not found my multiple image list of every product

Comment: Great! :) Now you have to make sure the path to the images is correct.

Comment: I keep my all image Images folder under the www-root folder.you can also see my database. here I also build a path.but why i can't show image

Comment: Firstly, If you are in .net core make sure you have app.UseStaticFiles(); in startup configure. If so, then try to include a hardcoded image to the view just to see if you can pinpoint one image correctly. If you can do that, you just have to compare the paths to find out what's different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222478/discussion-between-indrit-kello-and-shane-watson).